# Set ip as variable in cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd, ip

I am making a program in batch and I want to get the ip of a website and set it as a variable in the batch file. Please suggest a way to do that .
  Please Help

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for /f "tokens=3 delims=: " %%a in ('ping -n 1 www.google.com ^| find "Reply"') do (set ip=%%a)
Echo %ip%
```

Answer (score 0):

```dos
for /f "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%a in ('ping -n 1 www.google.com') do set "ip=%%a"
```

This will split the first line of output in the `ping` command using the square brackets around the ip address as delimiters. With the line splitted, the second token will be the ip address

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Windows, this can be done using a simple one line command.

The following will put your current public IP address in an envronment variable  `ipaddress`:

```
for /f "skip=4 usebackq tokens=2" %a in (`nslookup www.google.com resolver1.opendns.com`) do set ipaddress=%a
```

If you are using the `for` command inside a batch (`cmd`) file then `%` needs to be replaced by `%%` as follows:

```
for /f "skip=4 usebackq tokens=2" %%a in (`nslookup www.google.com resolver1.opendns.com`) do set ipaddress=%%a
```

See [FOR - Conditionally perform a command several times.](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html) for more information.